# Querying to parent and children to a JSON format from MySQL 5.6?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a heirarchy of tables in a MySQL 5.6 database that I need to query to a JSON format for use by a javascript tree structure.

Just as a test in my flask I did the following for just the top level

```
def get_all_customers():
    response_object = {'status': 'success'}

    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user="", password="", database="", host="localhost", port=3306)
    cursor = cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT idx, name FROM listcustomers ORDER BY name')
    data = []
    for idx, name in cursor:
        data.append({'id': idx, 'label':name, 'otherProp': "Customer"})
    response_object['customers'] = data

    return jsonify(response_object)
```

which returns

```
[
    { id: 1,
      label: "customer 1",
      otherProp: "Customer"
    },
    ...
]
```

But each customer has locations, and each location has areas, and each area has assets, and each asset has projects, and I need to also query them into children of this json object.  So, for example, just going one level deeper to locations, I would need something like this -

```
[
    { id: 1,
      label: "customer 1",
      otherProp: "Customer",
      children: [
                  {
                     id: 5,
                     label: "location 5",
                     otherProp: "Location"
                  },
                  ...
                ]
    },
    ...
]
```

where in my database `listlocatiosn` who links to `listcustomers` via the it's `parentCustomerId` column.  How can I manage this?  Eventually this tree will have about 13,000 objects so I know just querying the data and then parsing it with python would be far more inefficient than if I am able to query properly to begin with.

Comment: I bet on using AJAX requests in your JS code to server based on your needs. And you don't need to store entire tree in memory - you can just hide unnecessary parts. And by the way - MySQL supports JSON from 5.7 version

Comment: Yea I'm working on lazy loading now, but a big part of our tree component is being able to search for the lowest ranked items, and I don't see how I can do that without having that information actually present.  I think we're upgrading DB's soon though, this is probably a good enough reason to convince upstairs to move to 5.7 or something.

Comment: few comments also: 1) JSON format in MySQL isn't intended to store huge tree structures (I tried), 2) you can use TEMPORARY table with JSON fields to store current visible tree structure for particular user, 3) personally, I vote for using tree object model polling it with necessary data from DB and keeping it updated with necessary changes because simple lazy loading is prone to errors during change of data in DB

Comment: I'm not trying to keep things as a JSON in the database if that's what you mean, I want to query it into JSON. The tables and everything are already set up and turning them into a suitable JSON object would be a headache. Ive done this before with CTE with the built in python db, where my database was all tabular but I queried it into a nice JSON format.
The issue with polling is that the user needs to be able to use the search function, which searches the leafs, so if I don't have the leafs, its not going to be able to search.  I think i might have to make this tree from scratch.